# Adjustviewbounds works in the preview but not in the emulator

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

It works perfectly fine in the preview but in emulator the image gets white space in the left and right side in api 17. but when i tried in a different emulator with api 26 it worked perfectly fine. Is there another way to fix things like this.

code for the ImageView

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/snebakgrund"
            android:id="@+id/historikHeader"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

https://gyazo.com/056920e5f1772e34d09097186ffc0218 (preview)
https://gyazo.com/e6f774678352ca85265e44e1048c78b9 (emulator api.17)

Answer (score 0):

`'adjustViewBounds'` attribute requires images to be of a certain size or more to work (204 px or above in height ~ xxhdpi).